# talend open studio integrate with cloud

Tags: talend

Can 'Talend Open Studio - Data Integration' pull data from and push data to various available clouds? I checked on the internet but could not find the required information. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For sure it can!
For example, you can interact with Salesforce, Google, Azure, Amazon and so on, using dedicated components or standardized rest or soap APIs.
Can you detail detail a litle bit more your use case as someone will be able to give you good pointers?

Regards,
TRF